# Subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ closed proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ $\{{(x,y) | x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \land x,y > 0 \}}$. Is this set closed? I've already shown that it is not open, given that the complement is not closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's closed; how to prove this depends on exactly what your characterization of "open" and "closed" are. For example, if you know that a sequence is closed if and only if it contains all its limit points, then it suffices to note that this set is discrete and hence the only convergent sequences in this set are eventually constant.

Alternatively, if you can show that $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0, 0)\}$ is open then a few line modification gives the full result.